# Multiple getter methods for different amount of parameters

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor, getter

I know you can have multiple constructors, for example:

```
public Game (int num, boolean truth) {

}

public Game (int num) {
    this(num, false);
}
```

Can the same be done for getter methods? So I can have two parameters, but if the user only wants to use one, the other will automatically be filled in. Such as

```
public int wins (int num, boolean truth) {
    return num*2;
}

public int wins (int num) {
    this(num, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a delegate methods like:

```
public int wins (int num, boolean truth) {
    return num * 2;
}

public int wins (int num) {
    return wins(num, false);
}
```

In this case `this` keyword is use only to call constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, this is called [overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> ```
> public class DataArtist {
>     ...
>     public void draw(String s) {
>         ...
>     }
>     public void draw(int i) {
>         ...
>     }
>     public void draw(double f) {
>         ...
>     }
>     public void draw(int i, double f) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```